# trying to draw a rectangle and it is not showing up but there's no error

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I've created an animation loop that works fine, but when I created a function to draw a rectangle, nothing shows up. I don't get an error but the rectangle doesn't appear. I did console.log("hello") at the end of the rect function to make sure it works, and "hello" does appear in console, so at this point, I don't know what's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my complete code:

```
///// VARIABLES 

var canvas;
var ctx;
var w = 1000;
var h = 600; 

///// EXECUTABLE CODE 

setUpCanvas();


var o1 = {
    "x": w/3,
    "y": h/3,
    "w": 20,
    "h": 20,
    "c": 180,
    "a": 0.5,
    "angle": 0,
    "changle": 30,
    "distance": 50,

}

var o2 = {
    "x": w/3,
    "y": h/3,
    "c": 280,
    "a": 0.5,
    "w": 0,
    "h": 30, 
}


var oneDegree = 2*Math.PI/360;



setUpCanvas();



animationLoop();

rect(o2);

function animationLoop(){
    clear();
    shape(o1);
    angle(o1,2);
    forward(o1,10);

    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}

function clear(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
}


function shape(o){
    var x = o.x;
    var y = o.y;
    var a = o.angle;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(o.x,o.y);
    for ( var i=0; i<300; i++){
        angle(o, 10);
        forward(o,2+i*10);
        ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    o.x = x;
    o.y = y;
    o.angle = a;
}


function angle(o,a){ 
    // console.log(a);
    if( a == undefined){
        o.angle += o.changle;
    }else{
    o.angle += a;
    }
}


function forward(o,d){
    var cX;
    var cY;

    if(d != undefined){
        o.distance= d;    
    };
        cX = o.distance*Math.cos(o.angle*oneDegree*5);
        cY = o.distance*Math.sin(o.angle*oneDegree*5);
        o.x += cX;
        o.y += cY;
    
}


function rect(o){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(o.x , o.y);
    ctx.lineTo(o.x+o.w, o.y);
    ctx.lineTo(o.x+o.w, o.y+o.h);
    ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y+o.h);
    ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y);
    ctx.fillStyle = "hsla("+o.c+", 100%, 50%, "+o.a+")";
    ctx.fill();
   
}

//GENERAL STUFF
function randn(r){
    var result = Math.random()*r - r/2;
    return result;
}

function randi(r){
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random()*r);
    return result 
}

function rand(r){
    var result = Math.random()*r;
    return result
}

function setUpCanvas(){
    canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    canvas.style.border="2px solid black";
}

console.log("Assignment 2");
```

Comment: I can see some animation. What is the issue here?, where are you trying to see the rectangle. Can you send the screenshot of the output and point me to the code for rectange

Comment: I can see the rectangle actually.

Comment: hi @TechnoTech I'm trying to draw the rectangle on top of the animation, when I say rectangle i don't mean the outline of the canvas. The function "Rect" is where I wrote the code for the rectangle. And it's meant to be positioned at 1/3 of the canvas' width and 1/3 of the canvas' height.  All I'm seeing now is the animation within the canvas, but not the rectangle that's supposed to appear beneath the animation.

Comment: I have created a myRect method and created the rectangle using API, Now if I stop/comment out the animation I can see the my green rectangle, you need to check if the animation is overriding it

Answer (score 0):

I can see the rectangle, I changed the color of the rectangle to red to make it more visible to myself. Your code is correct. Did I miss anything?
here is the snippet, it just your code

```js
///// VARIABLES 

var canvas;
var ctx;
var w = 1000;
var h = 600; 

///// EXECUTABLE CODE 

setUpCanvas();

var o1 = {
    "x": w/3,
    "y": h/3,
    "w": 20,
    "h": 20,
    "c": 180,
    "a": 0.5,
    "angle": 0,
    "changle": 30,
    "distance": 50,

}

var o2 = {
    "x": w/3,
    "y": h/3,
    "c": 280,
    "a": 0.5,
    "w": 0,
    "h": 30, 
}


var oneDegree = 2*Math.PI/360;



setUpCanvas();

animationLoop();

rect(o2);
myRect(o2);

function animationLoop(){
    clear();
    shape(o1);
    angle(o1,2);
    forward(o1,10);

    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}

function clear(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
}


function shape(o){
    var x = o.x;
    var y = o.y;
    var a = o.angle;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(o.x,o.y);
    for ( var i=0; i<300; i++){
        angle(o, 10);
        forward(o,2+i*10);
        ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    o.x = x;
    o.y = y;
    o.angle = a;
}


function angle(o,a){ 
    // console.log(a);
    if( a == undefined){
        o.angle += o.changle;
    }else{
    o.angle += a;
    }
}


function forward(o,d){
    var cX;
    var cY;

    if(d != undefined){
        o.distance= d;    
    };
        cX = o.distance*Math.cos(o.angle*oneDegree*5);
        cY = o.distance*Math.sin(o.angle*oneDegree*5);
        o.x += cX;
        o.y += cY;
    
}

function myRect(o){
 
    //ctx.fillStyle = "hsla("+o.c+", 100%, 50%, "+o.a+")";
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.rect(o.x, o.y, o.x+o.w, o.y+o.h);
    ctx.stroke();
   
}

function rect(o){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(o.x , o.y);
    ctx.lineTo(o.x+o.w, o.y);
    ctx.lineTo(o.x+o.w, o.y+o.h);
    ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y+o.h);
    ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y);
    ctx.fillStyle = "hsla("+o.c+", 100%, 50%, "+o.a+")";
    ctx.fill();
   
}

//GENERAL STUFF
function randn(r){
    var result = Math.random()*r - r/2;
    return result;
}

function randi(r){
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random()*r);
    return result 
}

function rand(r){
    var result = Math.random()*r;
    return result
}

function setUpCanvas(){
    canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    canvas.style.border="2px solid red";
}

console.log("Assignment 2");
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```